# How can I detect when an Object is getting called in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How do I detect when a JavaScript object is being accessed? I mean like a scope object, not a global object or a property of a object. I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
"use strict"
!function() {
    var o = {
        onaccess: function() {
            console.log("o was accessed");
        }
    }
    var x = o; //"o was accessed" when this happens.
}();
```

Comment: I would dare to say that's not possible. The only way you can sense if something is accessing an object is through it's properties and methods. You must develop a mechanism that forces the use of the object in a certain way, and then take advantage of it and sense when the object is accessed.

Comment: `o` is a variable, not an object (there is no such thing as "scope object", if you discount `with`). The object itself isn't even accessed, as `o` only stores the reference to it, and now the same reference is getting stored in `x`.

Comment: You might be able to if you play around with [proxies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/get).  But I don't know about globally.

Comment: var x = o; //you are not accessing it here. 

you can create a generic getter and use that https://jsfiddle.net/karthick6891/z8y0ukf4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't that way as you are not accessing an object, but the reference to that object.

What you can try to do is to create a getter in the "global scope" (AKA `window` in browsers, for example) or to create an object with getters as properties, which you can think of "variables in objects".

```js
(function() {
    var _x = {};
    Object.defineProperty(window, 'x', {
        get: function() {
            alert("access");
            return _x;
        }
    });
    document.getElementById("g").addEventListener("click", function() {
        var a = x;
    });
    document.getElementById("w").addEventListener("click", function() {
        var a = window.x;
    });
})();
```

```html
<button id="g">Access global x</button>
<button id="w">Access window x</button>
```

This code works because when you acces a variable (`x` in this case), it will run through the upper scopes until it finds an scope which contains the variable. It will finally look for the variable in the global scope, which is `window`, where I've set a getter that will run each time `window.x` is called (or simply `x`, which will end in accessing `window.x` internally).

This is hacky and I don't recomment it as you have to define a global variable. You can however try to create an object with getters in some properties (the same way as `window.x`), so you don't have to work with the global scope, but this way you have to always access the object property by prepending the object:

```js
(function() {
  var _x = {};
  var prop = {};
  Object.defineProperty(prop, 'x', {
      get: function() {
          alert("access");
          return _x;
      }
  });
  document.getElementById("w").addEventListener("click", function() {
      var a = prop.x;
  });
})();
```

```html
<button id="w">Access property x</button>
```

Note that this will only work with predefined variable names. If you want to capture "all" variables, you can work with Proxies, which are impossible to hack over the global scope (window) but will work with objects, like this:

```js
var h = {
    get: function(target, name){
        alert("Accessed property " + name);
    }
};

var p = new Proxy({}, h);

document.getElementById("x").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var a = p.x;
});
document.getElementById("y").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var a = p.y;
});
document.getElementById("r").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var a = p[Math.random()];
});
```

```html
<button id="x">Access x property</button>
<button id="y">Access y property</button>
<button id="r">Access random property</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a proxy, then you can log something everytime your function is called, be careful though Proxies are not 100% polyfillable in IE11 or less

```
function realFunction() {
    return {
       a: "5"       
    }
}

var proxy = new Proxy(realFunction, {
    get: function(target, key) {
        const obj = target();
        console.log("key", `'${key}'`, "was called on", target);
            return obj[key];
        }
    });

proxy.a // "5"
```